# How to install postgis for a second postgresql instance on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis, ubuntu-16.04

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have an instance of postgresql-9.5 (on 5432 port) installed with postgis-2.2.2.

Because of a matter of compatibility with other systems, I need now to install an older postgresql-9.2 instance on the same machine that need also postgis extension. I managed to install 9.2 using 5433 port and works fine, but I can't figure out how to install postgis for this other instance.

Does anybody has any tip for doing this?

Comment: You'll need to connect to your new instance at port 5433 with a sql client (e.g. via pgAdmin) then install the extensions.

Comment: how you intalled postgis in your first instance? and what you tried and what happened in the second instance?